# hold animated frame in maya through expression

Tags: expression, maya

I am working on a short film where we are faking a clay look for clay-mation style animation.
We have five different bump maps that are set to being animated and looped.
This makes it look like the fingerprints move around on the character models while the frames play "as if someone went in and moved the clay character with their fingers" However, Maya does automatically switch the bump map out for every frame and we would like to hold each bump map for at least 10 frames before maya should go to the next image file.

Currently we have this expression piped into the animation of the file node. All it does is loop the five different texture we have, however, it loops through all five in five frames.

```
sha1:file10.frameExtension=(frame%5);
```

Any idea how I can add to the expression so that it holds a texture file for a certain ammount of frames?

Comment: I get the error expression -e -s "sha1:file10.frameExtension=(frame / holdframes %  4);"  -o "" -ae 1 -uc all  expression1;
    // Error: Attribute not found or variable missing '$':  holdframes
    // Error: Expression invalid after edit. //

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try   `sha1:file10.frameExtension=(frame / holdframes %  number_of_textures);`

**EDIT**

on further discussion below, it seems like OP wants a variable length hold.   The problem is that the expression has no memory, it's supposed to be time independent so it can't 'remember' how long it has been on a current frame.

I think the right answer here really is to generate a long-ish animation on the frame number using stepped integer key frames to randomize the frame number, and then make that animation loop forever using post tangents.

Comment: I tried but I get the following error: 
    expression -e -s "sha1:file10.frameExtension=(frame / holdframes %  4);"  -o "" -ae 1 -uc all  expression1;

    // Error: Attribute not found or variable missing '$':    
holdframes // 
// Error: Expression invalid after edit. //

Comment: you need to make a variable called holdframes to tell the expression how many frames you want to hold each frame of your texture

Comment: I used 
int $x;
$x=rand(3, 4);
sha1:file10.frameExtension=(frame / $x %  4)
It seems to hold the frame for less than 3 frames sometime though. Why is that?

Comment: `for($frame=0; $frame<100; $frame++)
{
int $x = rand(7, 17);
print("Frame " + $frame + ": " + $frame / $x % 17 + "\n");
}` this should print random numbers between 7 and 17 but if you run the MEL lines you can see that it also prints numbers below 7. Why is that?

Comment: You're getting a different demominator every time, so your number is varying from (0/7) = 0 to (100/17) = 60-something.  You're then getting that number modulo 17.  both low and high numbers can produce values lower than 7:  1 % 17 = 1,  35 % 17 = 1, and so on. Do you nean $frame / ($x % 17) ?

Comment: I don't think the $frame would do any good, because the rand() should not be affected by the current frame number, but simply just pick numbers between 7 and 17. If the first number or the rand command is the demominator, then how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this expression.
It generates random numbers, but they are predictable at the same time. 
That means that I could generate an animation curve ranging between 7 and 16 frames of length, then delete the expression once the keys had been set and plugging the animation curve into the image number.

```
int $init;
int $r;
int $t;
int $x;

// main loop
$time = `currentTime -query`;
seed(int($time));

// every time we go through '0'
if( $time == 1 ) {
    print ("\n time == 1");

int $r = 7;
int $t =1 ;
int $x =1 ;

$r = int(rand(7,16));
$x = int(rand(0,5));
if( $x == 5 ) 
    $x = 4;
}

// safety: '$r' can not be zero
if( $r == 0 ) 
$r = int(rand(7,16));

// get modulo per frame
$t = int($time % $r);

if( $r == ($t + 1) ) {
    $r = int(rand(7,16));
$x = int(rand(0,5));
if( $x == 5 ) 
    $x = 4;
print ("\n"+$time+" texture: "+$x+" - for: "+$r);
}

//print ("\n"+$time+" "+$r+" "+$t+" "+$x);
//zackBodyFingerprintsBmp_file.frameExtension=$x;
setAttr "zackBodyFingerprintsBmp_file.frameOffset" $x;
setKeyframe { "zackBodyFingerprintsBmp_file.frameOffset" };
```